# Youtube Data Api - Members Endpoint - Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Description:

I'm encountering an issue while implementing the YouTube Data API in my Node.js backend.

I keep getting the following error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
        "domain": "youtube.common",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've already set up the OAuth flow, obtained the access token, and ensured the correct scopes. Here are the scopes I've included:

```js
scope: [
  'email',
  'profile',
  'openid',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
]
```

Surprisingly, I can successfully send a comment to a YouTube live video using the same process, but when it comes to the Members API, it's not working as expected.

Here's the non-functional code snippet:

```js
async requestMembers({
  access,
  refresh,
}: {
  access: string;
  refresh: string;
}) {
  const url = `${'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/'}members?part=snippet`;
  fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
}
```

And here's the working code snippet for sending comments:

```js
sendComment = (text: string, access_token: string, id: string) => {
  const url = `${'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/'}liveChat/messages?part=snippet`;
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippet: {
        liveChatId: id,
        type: 'textMessageEvent',
        textMessageDetails: {
          messageText: text,
        },
      },
    }),
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log('send comment - ', data));
};
```

I've double-checked the OAuth setup, ensured correct scopes, and compared it with the working comment-sending code, but the Members API request remains unauthorized. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!